# After upgrading Rails from 5.1 to 5.2 I got following warning messages

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, aws-sdk

After upgrading Rails from 5.1 to 5.2 I got the following warning messages.

```
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::AWS::CDN
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::CDN::AWS is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::AWS::Compute
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::Compute::AWS is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::AWS::DNS
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::DNS::AWS is deprecated
[fog][DEPRECATION] Unable to load Fog::AWS::Storage
[fog][DEPRECATION] The format Fog::Storage::AWS is deprecated
```

Gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2'
gem 'fog-aws'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: The issue was already reported: https://github.com/fog/fog-aws/issues/466

Comment: I see but How I can fix in my system

Comment: @Rajnik the issue has not been resolved, yet. There is an [open PR](https://github.com/fog/fog-aws/pull/467) which is supposed to fix the deprecation warnings by renaming the affected constants.

Comment: If you *really* want to "fix" the problem immediately, you could point your `Gemfile` at that fork: https://github.com/jaredbeck/fog-aws/tree/fix_cdn_dpr_warn ... But I wouldn't recommend this. The *deprecation warning* is only a *warning*; nothing is actually *broken*. I would advise simply waiting patiently for the official library update that resolves the warning; *probably* by merging the above PR.

Comment: FYI – the bug was fixed in v3.3.0 (Sep 18)

Comment: @Stefan I am using `fog-aws-3.5.1` but still getting these warnings.

Answer (score 4):

I have solved it by adding gem fog-core 2.1.0 :)

Comment: I resolved this issue by downgrading fog-core from 2.2.3 to 2.1.0

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same bug with `fog-openstack`.
It seems like the latest version of fog is not totally clean (see source below).
I solved this bug by downgrading `fog-openstack` to the previous version (ie `gem "fog-openstack", '~>0.1.23'`).

Source https://github.com/fog/fog/issues/4014